# Kubernetes cluster via kubeadm - CoreDNS buffer size too small / Pods network problems

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, internal-dns, kubeadm, weave

I am new to deploying on-premise Kubernetes clusters. I managed to deploy one using `kubeadm` with `weave` CNI.

Internet connection inside Pods is somewhat sluggish / non-working. I am trying to deploy Self-Hosted GitHub Actions Runner which is accessing GitHub API. For example accessing `*.github.com` FQDN from Pods will result in this **error** (*coredns Pod Logs*):
`[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 api.github.com. A: dns: buffer size too small`

I also observed that Pods won't connect to Ubuntu or Debian servers but `nslookup` inside pod works (*using `dnsutils` pod from K8s*).

Host machine can access every site so I assume that there is no problem in Firewall.

`ufw` and `iptables` are disabled.

I set `bufsize` to `512`, `1024` and `4096` but still the same error. By default `bufsize` in ConfigMap is not defined, but It gave me the same error.

CoreDNS ConfigMap (`$ kubectl describe configmap coredns -n kube-system`):

```yaml
Name:         coredns
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
Corefile:
----
.:53 {
    bufsize 4096
    errors
    health {
       lameduck 5s
    }
    ready
    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
       pods insecure
       fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
       ttl 30
    }
    prometheus :9153
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
       max_concurrent 1000
    }
    cache 30
    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
}
BinaryData
====
Events:  <none>
```

#### How I deployed Cluster:

```bash
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=172.30.0.0/16 --service-cidr=172.16.0.0/16 --cri-socket=unix:/run/cri-dockerd.sock

kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane-

# Install weave
sudo curl -L git.io/weave -o /usr/local/bin/weave
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/weave

# Download weave DaemonSet from Github
wget https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/releases/download/v2.8.1/weave-daemonset-k8s.yaml
```

Edit to:

```yaml
...
containers:
  - name: weave
    env:
      - name: IPALLOC_RANGE
    value: 172.30.0.0/16
...
```

Finally: `kubectl apply -f ./weave-daemonset-k8s.yaml`

---

Versions:

```bash
$ kubectl version
    Client Version: v1.28.2
    Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
    Server Version: v1.28.2

$ kubectl describe configmap coredns -n kube-system
    image: registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.10.1
```

---

What can be the cause?

Tried:

- `kubeadm` reset
- Different CIDR for Node and Service
- Default `weave` config
- Edit `weave`config - `IPALLOC_RANGE` to match Node CIDR
- `dnsutils` Pods

  - `github.com`

    - `nslookup` & `dig` - Success
    - `ping` - Failure - unknown host - buffer too small Error
  - `api.github.com`

    - `nslookup` - buffer too small Error
    - `dig` - Success
  - `kubernetes.io`

    - `nslookup` & `dig` - Success

Expectations:

- Working network connection in Pods
- Successful DNS resolution

---

**EDIT**

---

I updated **CoreDNS** to version **1.11.0** and now there is no **buffer too small** error but instead it shows **Request Timed out**. At least I can see that it is correctly trying to Query from my main DNS which I tested multiple times and works as expected.

---

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am using coredns 1.11.0 and getting buffer size too small when trying to ping `login.microsoft.com` but every other site I tried works find

Comment: I had to revert coredns to 1.9.4 to get around this. This will do for now since it is a local docker desktop for windows issue only apparently. The Azure k8s works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the latest CoreDNS does not support DNS compression and the response goes over the limit 512 bytes (UDP limit).

First ping/wget... the address that does not work.

To trace the bag run:

`kubectl get pods -n kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns`

`kubectl logs  coredns-xxxxxxx -n kube-system`

You will see the following in the results

```
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 checkip.amazonaws.com. A: dns: buffer size too small.
```

Modify 'forward' in the config

```
kubectl edit configmap coredns -n kube-system

forward .  /etc/resolv.conf {
          force_tcp
          max_concurrent 1000
        }
```

Save & Restart Docker Desktop
Here is more about forward attribute https://coredns.io/plugins/forward/